# Page not found (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm making website using Python Framework of 'Django'.

I have some problems with Django about entering.

The page for http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/1%EC%9B%94/ should be uploaded when the January link is clicked, otherwise Page not found (404) will appear.

I'd like to know what's wrong and how to fix it.

**project/urls.py contains:**

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from bookmark.views import BookmarkListView, BookmarkDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bookmark/', include('bookmark.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

**blog/urls.py contains:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from blog import views

app_name='blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # Example: /blog/
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # Example: /blog/post/ (same as /blog/)
    path('post/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),

    # Example: /blog/post/django-example/
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/
    path('archive/', views.PostArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/
    path('archive/<int:year>/', views.PostYearArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.PostMonthArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_month_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/10/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/', views.PostDayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_day_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/today/
    path('archive/today/', views.PostTodayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_today_archive'),
]
```

**blog/views.py contains:**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView, \
    DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView

from blog.models import Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_all.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostArchiveView(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'

class PostYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    make_object_list = True

class PostMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    month_format = '%m'

class PostDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    month_format = '%m'

class PostTodayArchiveView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
```

**blog/models.py contains:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='TITLE', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField('SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True, help_text='one word for title alias.')
    description = models.CharField('DESCRIPTION', max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='simple description text.')
    content = models.TextField('CONTENT')
    create_dt = models.DateTimeField('CREATE DATE', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_dt = models.DateTimeField('MODIFY DATE', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'
        db_table = 'blog_posts'
        ordering = ('-modify_dt',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_previous(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_modify_dt()

    def get_next(self):
        return self.get_next_by_modify_dt()
```

**post_archive_year.html**

```
<h1>Post Archives for {{ month|date:"N, Y" }}</h1>

<div>
    <ul>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <li>
            {{ post.modify_dt|date:"Y-m-d" }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**post_archive_month.html**

```
<h1>Post Archives for {{ month|date:"N, Y" }}</h1>

<div>
    <ul>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <li>
            {{ post.modify_dt|date:"Y-m-d" }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For that generic view, month_format by default is set to %b (first three chars of month name in English). Your link does not match that format, so it returns 404.

Comment: Then, where and how should I fix it?

Comment: Just looked again at your code and it looksl ike in views.py you set month_format to %m, which takes a number for the month. Your urls.py though is set to match a string.

Comment: Actually, I'm writing this code while reading a book. The code in the original book does not have %m. So I added it just in case, but if there is no %m, where else should I fix?

Comment: I don't think you can use hangul with the generic views. How did you generate the link with hangul?